# UIViewController XIB in iOS framework or dependent project

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

I know this sort of question has been banded about before but I've not found the one definitive answer to the question I'm facing myself with at the moment. And that is **within a library, how best to ship a `UIViewController` subclass with a complex view**?

The methods I can see are:

1. Ship the XIB as well and ask that users of your code add it to their project. This is undesirable in my opinion as it makes maintenance a nightmare. If you add a view controller to your library project then you have to add the new XIB to each and every project which uses the library.
2. Create your view in `loadView` / `viewDidLoad` and take the pain of doing everything manually in there. This could be extremely complex though for complex view hierarchies.
3. Somehow generate your `loadView` code from your XIB at compile time. Sounds complex to get something that would do this properly though.

What I don't quite understand is how Apple do it. With the `MessageUI` framework for example, there is `MFMailComposeViewController` which is a pretty complex view but there's no XIB for it (or at least not that I know of anyway - maybe there actually is?). I'd be interested to know how Apple do it - does anyone know?

Comment: Apple use IB for certain things, but any UI code they have is already going to be compiled and on the device. There'd be no need to include it in the development kit since you can't make changes to what's on the device anyway. The UI for MessageUI is actually fairly simple. If they did use a nib for that, it's probably shared with mail, but for that, they probably just create it in code.

Comment: It's not *that* simple. I'm going by what I can see in the `MessageUI` binary that comes with the SDK. I can see that it's got a method called `initWithComposition:` which is slightly confusing since I can't quite find out what is calling that.

Comment: No I understand that now. There's another controller object and a view which appear to do the heavy lifting of that view. So, yes, they do it all in code basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're coding everything from scratch, manually, which is, in my opinion, is the best choice. Sometimes InterfaceBuilder can really hijack your porject by applying unkown/badly documented settings etc., plus the code is less portable. For example, one with an unofficial toolchain for Linux, for example, might be unable to use the library without Interface Builder. Code has to be written by the developer, be able to be compiled with just a proper, but minimalistic toolchain (compiler+assembler+linker), without being dependent on any IDEs, SDKs or other technologies not strictly belonging to the programming part of one's project.

Comment: That's a fair point, I see where you're coming from on that one. I guess I just have not really started trying to use `loadView` enough yet to see how long-winded it makes the code.